# Rails - Heroku push fails and results in uninitialized constant Log4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, compilation, stripe-payments

**For my application, I have recently set up Stripe and Oauth.  It runs great locally, but when I try to push up to herokuapp (git push heroku master) it results in the following compiling error. How do I solve this?**

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   uninitialized constant Log4r
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/config/environments/production.rb:87:in `block in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:95:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
   /tmp/build_1s1esoyyqqqcw/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary => assets:environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
```

I'm not sure if the items below matter or impacts it.

**production.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( stripe_form.js )
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the two lines in production.rb:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

And now it pushes up to heroku succesfully.